# One app receives the broadcast while the other one does not. Why?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms, android-broadcast

I have 3 applications that are dependent on each other. for instance, Client app, Browser and launcher. My requirement is when the client is uninstalled(only when the client) i want the other two apps to be uninstalled as well. For this what i have done so far is, i have written a broadcast receiver(in both the apps) that listens for package removed. if the package removed is my client, i start an alarm that launches the uninstall procedure(individually on both apps). Why the alarm? because i want the uninstall pop up to come up til the user uninstalls the app. The issue i am currently facing is that, sometimes the launcher app does not get the broadcast or so i think. and hence it does not initiate the uninstall. Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. I am not able to figure out the cause of this problem. below is the code written in the launcher:

**The broadcast receiver** :

```
public class UnistallBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
            String packagename = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
            if (packagename.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.nanoheal")) {
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmIntent.class);
                intent1.putExtra("appnamel", "com.nanoheal.launcher");

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 325,
                        intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 30, pi);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**the Alarm Intent:**

```
public class AlarmIntent extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("AlarmIntent", "Intent fired by Launcher");
        mContext = context;
        try {
            String appLauncher = intent.getStringExtra("appnamel");
            if (appLauncher != null) {
                if (isAppInstalled(appLauncher)) {

                    Uri packageURI2 = Uri.parse("package:" + appLauncher);
                    Intent uninstallIntent2 = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageURI2);
                    uninstallIntent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(uninstallIntent2);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
        boolean installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            installed = false;
        }
        Log.d("AlarmIntent", "Launcher-IsAppInstalled " + packageName + " "
                + installed);
        return installed;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you set the minutes and seconds to 0?

Comment: it was sort of like a hack i tried, its redundant, the code works exactly the same way even of those two lines are removed. i forgot to remove the lines before pasting the code.

Comment: Please, specify if `UnistallBroadcast.onReceive()` and `AlarmIntent.onReceive()` are called for every app (you have got logging for `AlarmIntent` but not for `UnistallBroadcast`) in case of client unistall.

Comment: I am still not sure as to why this was happening! but I removed the priority which i had given in the intent filter of UninstalBroadcast in manifest file. And it started working well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very certain about the  details of how and why.
 But i changed **this**

```
<receiver android:name="package.UnistallBroadcast" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**to**

```
<receiver android:name="package.UnistallBroadcast" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and it worked fine. As far as i know if the priority is set for a receiver the one with the highest priority should get the action first. but strangely, in my case i was not getting the action for the receiver i gave priority.

Comment: "The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000." - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Maybe 1000 crashes the whole receiver.